# Recursive SQL command and duplicate results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if how I am handling removing duplicate results using `DISTINCT` is the best way to approach my recursive call. Here is my code sample:

```
with cte as(
SELECT
dbo.Users.Username,
dbo.Contacts.FirstName,
dbo.Contacts.LastName,
tenant.Name,
tenant.Id,
tenant.ParentTenantId
FROM
dbo.Tenants AS tenant
INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON tenant.Id = dbo.Users.TenantId
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Users.ContactId = dbo.Contacts.Id
where tenant.Id = '6CD4C969-C794-4C95-9CA2-5984AEC0E32C'

union all

SELECT 
dbo.Users.Username,
dbo.Contacts.FirstName,
dbo.Contacts.LastName,
childTenant.Name,
childTenant.Id,
childTenant.ParentTenantId
FROM
dbo.Tenants AS childTenant
INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON childTenant.Id = dbo.Users.TenantId
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Users.ContactId = dbo.Contacts.Id
INNER JOIN cte on childTenant.ParentTenantId  = cte.Id)

select DISTINCT UserName, FirstName, LastName, Name, Id, ParentTenantId  from cte ORDER BY Id
```

here are the results:
[image: results of distinct]

Here are the results without using the `DISTINCT` key word
[image]

While `DISTINCT` works I am wondering if it is the best way to handle the duplicate results or if I should rework my query somehow.

Comment: How many record do you get back? If it's relatively few, don't worry about it and just DISTINCT them.

Comment: Less than 100k I would imagine.

Comment: In one of the joined tables, there must be duplicate rows for the joined columns. If you do a DISTINCT on this table or modify the join to get distinct rows, then you would operate on a smaller subset of the data, improving performance.

Comment: @JosephB, I think the join on the INNER JOIN dbo.Users ON tenant.Id = dbo.Users.TenantId could be causing it, because for each parent that comes back it is also bringing back the children each time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether that is the case here, but it is a common misunderstanding that distinct is a function that applies to a certain column. Distinct applies to the row, that is:

`select distinct(x), y from t`

is the same as:

`select distinct x, y from t` or `select distinct x, (y) from t`

Furthermore:

`select x, distinct(y) from t`

is an invalid construction

Comment: You are correct. The parenthesis were not supposed to be there.